# Getting the error: "Invalid JSON payload received." with a javax.ws.rs.core.Response while sending a String

Tags: java, google-api, response

I am trying to connect with Google API, but I am having an issue when sending my authentication request. I am sending a string body, but the request seems to be receiving a JSON somehow.

Here is the code:

```
public Response getGoogleAuth(@QueryParam("state") String state,
        @QueryParam("code") String code,
        @QueryParam("scope") String scope) {
    try {
        // Get the refresh and access token from Google, they also expire in 1 hour
        String body = "code=" + code + "&"
                + "client_id=" + {googleClientId} + "&"
                + "client_secret=" + {googleClientSecret} + "&"
                + "redirect_uri=" + {url} + "&"
                + "grant_type=authorization_code";

        webTarget = client.target("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token");

        Response response = webTarget.request()
                .header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                .post(Entity.text(body), Response.class);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        String responseString = response.readEntity(String.class);
        
        // Error
        if (responseString.contains("error")) {
            return Response.status(200).entity("Error while authenticating user: " + responseString).build();
        }
       
        return Response.status(200).entity("User authorized: ").build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(113).entity("Error while authorizing the user" + e.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

For the responseString response I get the following response:

> "error": {
> "code": 400,
> "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.\ncode=4/???\n^",
> "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
> }

Knowledge:

- **googleClientId** = The client ID obtained from the Google API Console.
- **googleClientSecret** = The client secret obtained from the Google API Console.
- **url** = One of the redirect URIs listed for your project in the Google API Console.

Can anyone help me check what is the issue? Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java ? Perhaps it is not best to re-invent the wheel, or is there a reason you need to write this yourself?

Comment: Even if I use the api-client-library, this issue may present itself on other occasions. I was not using the library since I had started developing on and app that had already started with the more manual way of connecting to the API.